# SQL Server - Hide databases and limit user to see one View object only

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view, sql-server-2012

As per title, I would like to create a user in SQL Server 2012 where that user:

1. can only see 1 database among other databases (Let's say TestDB)
2. can only see 1 view among other views AND tables in TestDB (Let's say TestView)

So to hide all other databases, I execute this command:

```
USE master;
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO TestUser;
Use TestDB;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::TestDB TO TestUser;
```

Now, how can I limit TestUser to only see TestView (deny other tables and views)?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set DENY VIEW DEFINITION on all views except TestView.

```
  DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON NonTestView TO TestUser
```

Comment: So I need to do one by one for all the views and tables? Thought might have a more efficient way if there is.

Comment: You can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[VIEWS] to create the statements.  Like this:  SELECT 'DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON ' + TABLE_NAME + ' TO TestUser'
  FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[VIEWS].   Just remove the result for TestView.